# error using save can't write file

Tags: matlab, windows-7, save

I have got this really strange error in matlab. When I try to run the command

```
save(fullfile('filepath','filename'),'var','-v7');
```

I get the error message,

```
error using save can't write file
```

but when I try

```
save(fullfile('filepath','filename'),'var','-v7.3');
```

everything works fine. The the variable takes some space on the workspace, 165MB, but the I would guess that the size should not be an issue here. Does anyone know why it does not work to save in `v7`?

For the one that want to confirm the size of the variable, I will add the `whos` information,

```
Name      Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes
myName    1x1             173081921  struct
```

BR/ Patrik

**EDIT**

The variable I try to save is a struct with plenty of fields. I have tried to save a 3 dimensional matrix of size 800 mb, which went through without problems.

Comment: Sadly that does not work either, matlab does not even recognize the option. However, saving eg a variable `a = 1` with the option `-v7`, works great as well.

Comment: what about this: **save file.mat a -v7**    ? does this work?

Comment: Sadly, no. However `'save(fullfile('filepath','filename'),'var','-v7');` and `save file.mat a -v7` does both create a file, however the file is corrupted on row 2 and I still get the error message.

Comment: what is you matlab version?

Comment: My version is MATLAB R2013a

Comment: Fwiw, in Linux / matlab R2019b, I got the error "can not write file" when using save, suddenly, when starting a copy operation from the explorer in adjacent/parent directories. Finishing the copying and closing the explorer, saving worked again.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact match to your problem, but I received the same error message when trying to save to -v6 format. Matlab is supposed to issue an error when a variable type or size is not supported:

```
help save
...
If any data items require features that the specified version does not support, MATLAB does not save those items and issues a warning. You cannot specify a version later than your version of MATLAB software.
```

Matlab's error checking seems to not be perfect, because there are certain situations (dependent on Matlab version and the particular variable type) that just fail all together with this not so helpful error message:

```
Error using save
Can't write file filename.mat.
```

For example, saving a string with certain unicode characters with the '-v6' option in Matlab r2015b in Linux produces the error, but Matlab r2016a in Windows does not. This is the output from my Matlab r2015b session:

```
>> A=char(double(65533))
A =
?
>> save('filename.mat','-v6','A')
Error using save
Can't write file filename.mat.
```

Without having your specific variable to test with, but seeing that the error messages match, I suggest removing parts of your data structure until it will save in order to isolate the variable that is causing it to fail.

Comment: This was not exactly the case. I only remember this vaguely after all years. I do not really remember how I solved it, but I think I managed to change version somehow. Still, when I had this problem the same data could either work or give an error. I believe there was some known issue with format v6.